# phantomjs only serving index page when running a curl command

Tags: angularjs, ajax, curl, ember.js, seo

I am using [ajax-seo](https://github.com/liuwenchao/ajax-seo) to index my angularjs app to crawlers. I followed all the instruction to setup the same. After running `curl mydomain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/` the `phantomjs` is serving the `index` page well, but when I try to access the other pages with `curl mydomain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/id/1`, it still serves the same index page.

When the same page is accessed on the web with url `mydomain.comf/id/1` it gives the proper result. Any help on this?